# Bought a 5.1 Channel surround speakers but my computer only has one audio input

Tags: audio, speakers

So I'm dumb for not knowing that my sound card only supports one audio input, the speakers arrived today and need three ports, I was thinking is a 3 way splitter going to do the magic or no?

Thanks for your time, I know I'm super dumb, please don't flame

Comment: Most modern sound cards actually do more than one output. Could you add a photo of your sound card back panel? Likewise/alternatively, what your PC is, and what the speakers are.

Comment: Dont you mean one audio *output*?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one audio output on your board (should be green) then that means it supports only Stereo channel sound. You would either need to get a new mother board that supported 5.1 channel sound or install a sound card into your computer.

Even if you split the single output into three 3.5mm outputs it won't be true 5.1 sound. With Stereo channeled sound it divides between two speakers (Left/Right). 5.1 essentially splits the sound into Left Back, Left Front, Center, Right Front, and Right Back. I also don't think Stereo doesn't account for a sub woofer but could probably be made to work. Simple solution would be a sound card.